# Fake a change for ActiveModel dirty or mimic 'touching' a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I can't think of a better way to title this Sorry!

Ultimately I have a callback that 99% of the time I only want to run when a particular list of attributes get changed. But in a couple of cases I'd love to be able to by pass my `return unless previous_changes & watched_attributes`.

Is there any way to mock a change to a particular attribute? Somehow set `model.attribute_changed?` to true?

I've been using `model.touch` but `updated_at` is a column I deliberately want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check whether your attribute is changed or not by using following command

```
@object.column_changed? #=> true
```

You can get an array of changed attributes by using changed method

```
@object.changed #=> ['column_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
object.attribute_name_will_change!
object.changed << :attribute_name
puts object.attribute_name_changed?
puts object.changed?
```

resulting output is:

```
true
true
```

attribute_name is to be replaced with the name of your attribute.